# Take form data passed via url and populate a new form

Tags: jquery, forms

My payment processor passes a few form fields in the url to my member site registration form...first name, last name and email.

I want to use the email value to automatically populate the username fields in the registration form.

```
<input type="text" value="" size="10" name="username" class="fld">
<input type="text" value="" size="15" name="firstname" class="fld">
<input type="text" value="" size="15" name="lastname" class="fld">
<input type="email" value="" size="25" name="email" class="fld">
<input type="password" size="10" name="password1" class="fld">
```

I also want the pass the username, first, last and email as hidden field and just display their value as text...so these three filed can not be changed when the form is submitted.

I was also wondering if there is a way to force the form to submit when the payment processor sends the data over to the registration form via the url?

That way the user does not have to stop and fill you the registration form, since I can collect all the data via the payment processor, including a password.

Is jquery the best way to do this...and how?

What the form looks like with the input fields:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Here is part of the code for the registration form.

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wpm_registration ui-sortable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="li_fld systemFld required">
                <td class="label">Username:</td>
                <td class="fld_div">
                        <input type="text" value="" size="10" name="username" class="fld">
                        <div class="desc"></div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="li_fld required wp_field">
                <td class="label">First Name:</td>
                <td class="fld_div">
                        <input type="text" value="" size="15" name="firstname" class="fld">
                        <div class="desc"></div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="li_fld required wp_field">
                <td class="label">Last Name:</td>
                <td class="fld_div">
                        <input type="text" value="" size="15" name="lastname" class="fld">
                        <div class="desc"></div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="li_fld systemFld">
                <td class="label">E-mail:</td>
                <td class="fld_div">
                        <input type="email" value="" size="25" name="email" class="fld">
                        <div class="desc"></div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="li_fld systemFld">
                <td class="label">Password (twice):</td>
                <td class="fld_div">
                        <input type="password" size="10" name="password1" class="fld"><br>
                        <input type="password" size="10" name="password2" class="fld">
                        <div class="desc">Password has to be at least 8 characters long<br>and must not contain spaces</div>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="li_submit">
                <td class="label">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="fld_div form_button">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Registration" class="fld button">
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, try to check if the information is already in the input. If it's the case, replace the input by it value :

```
$(function() {
     $('input.fld').each(function() {
         if($(this).val() != '') {
             var val = $(this).val();
             $(this).parent().text(val);
         }
     });
});
```

That's it !